# Свойства объекта MouseEvent

Tags: javascript

В чем отличие этих свойств объекта `MouseEvent`?

1. `clientX/Y`,
2. `layerX/Y`,
3. `pageX/Y`,
4. `screenX/Y`,
5. И просто `X/Y`?
6. **Только что еще `offsetX/Y` заметил.**

Большинство из них одинаково. И отличие `screenX/Y` от остальных понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Координаты курсора мыши относительно окна.
2. Относительно ближайшего слоя-родителя. Если элемент, который вызвал событие является слоем (то есть имеет значение свойства position отличное от static), то координата будет высчитываться относительно этого элемента.
3. Относительно документа.
4. Координаты относительно монитора.
5. Псевдоним `clientX/Y`.
6. Показывает отступ курсора мыши по оси X/Y от края целевого DOM узла.

Comment: В каком случае относительно окна и относительно документа будут разными?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Они всегда будут разными.

Comment: Что-то не похоже...

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Почему бы не сделать сниппет, в котором все перечисленные будут разными?

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошее предложение. Отдам решение тому, кто это организует. Хотя некоторые наверняка повторяться будут (5-ый пункт, просто алиас).